# ASP.NET Core DB First scaffolding Join doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I've created a test ASP.NET Core project. I've generated the models from an existing DB using the  Scaffold-DbContext command.

Everything went fine. I've added an ApiController to return the data, and if I query, using LINQ, simple flat table data or I make joins on tables where the foreign keys have been explicitly defined in the DB it works.

But if I make a query joining two tables **where the foreign keys have not been set it doesn't return anything**.

Please note that the two tables are related to each other by an integer ID (*MktId*).

Entity models generated by the scaffold:

```
public partial class MonthlyPrice
{
    public int MpId { get; set; }        
    public int MktId { get; set; }
    public int CmId { get; set; }
    public decimal MpPrice { get; set; }

    public Commodities Cm { get; set; }
    public Currencies Cur { get; set; }
    public PriceTypes Pt { get; set; }
    public UnitOfMeasure Um { get; set; }
}

public partial class Commodities
{
    public Commodities()
    {
        MonthlyPriceItem = new HashSet<MonthlyPriceItem>();
    }

    public int CmId { get; set; }
    public string CmName { get; set; }
    public int CmCatId { get; set; }

    public ICollection<MonthlyPrice> MonthlyPriceItem { get; set; }
}

public partial class Markets
{
    public int MktId { get; set; }
    public string MktName { get; set; }
}
```

the following query return results:

```
var price= (from m in db.MonthlyPrice
           join c in db.Commodities on m.CmId equals c.CmId
           select new
           {
               c.CmName,
               m.MpPrice
           });
```

**but this one doesn't return anything:**

```
var price= (from m in db.MonthlyPrice
           join mk in db.Markets on m.MktId equals mk.MktId
           select new
           {
               m.MpPrice,
               mk.MktName
           });
```

Please note that **both queries on Entity Framework 6.x on ASP.NET 4.7 works perfectly**.

**Should I have to specify all the foreign key in the DB to make EFCore works correctly?**

*(Db is not always designed by me!!)*

**UPDATE**

The model builder for the Markets has been **generated by scaffold-dbcontext command** like the following:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Markets1>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasKey(e => e.MktId);

    entity.ToTable("__Markets");

    entity.Property(e => e.MktId).HasColumnName("mkt_id");

    entity.Property(e => e.MktName)
        .IsRequired()
        .HasColumnName("mkt_name")
        .HasMaxLength(250);    
});
```

Respect to the one generated for Commodities table I've noticed that there is the line **entity.ToTable("__Markets");** that looks very strange to me.

Comment: It looks like the one-to-many relationship between `MonthlyPrice` and `Market` is not configured (correctly at least) in the database. Moreover, should `Commodity` and `Market` have many-to-many relationship with `MonthlyPrice` being the intermediate table?

Comment: @David Liang but if the number of the ID used for the join matches, why it doesn't return anything?? Sometimes foreign keys are not configured in the database even if they are there. With EF6 I've never had this problem

Comment: if this database is pre-existing you might want to reverse engineer your context with the command-line.  This way it will hopefully get valid starting point.   Keep in mind that the underlying changes are to EF Core don't fall one to one with predecessors, i.e. if it worked in EF6 it should work in Core. Not always the case.

Comment: @mvermef scaffold-dbcontext is the command to create models from the db. So, you're telling me that is impossible what I've faced and there's errors in the data for sure?

Comment: No I am saying that config you have might not match what the DB has and this doesn't mean you can't get it right, you just have to research a little more to get the one to one configured correctly in your code first. It probably just needs tweaks at you code level. I was just suggesting that reverse scaffolding could possibly give the relationships

Comment: @mvermef but the code I've posted already come from the scaffold. It's not written by me.

Comment: Reread, sorry, yes you going to have to define foreign keys otherwise you get the results you getting, also you might run into shadow properties.  So yes, you probably need to define via attributes or fluent, the relationships.

Comment: What does `OnModelCreating` on the `DbContext` look like?

Comment: @ESG added the modelBuilder inside onModelCreating of the table that cause issues. Effectively there's a strange line of code I've never seen before: entity.ToTable("__Markets");

Comment: There does not need to be a foreign key for this to work. Is there more than one Markets table in the database, or more than one Markets DbSet? Your generated class is `Markets` but the code you are showing in your edit is configuring `Markets1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you want to fight with it a bit:

Update to at least .NET Core 2.1

Preserve the original database names to remove the funk in the migration. Use the -UseDatabaseNames option.

```
scaffold-dbcontext  -UseDatabaseNames
```

2. Else, continue:

Annotations might be valuable either way if your ids or table names on the current database are funky (spaces, prefixes, etc...)

Add Markets to MonthlyPrice Class as a foreign key. Make the ids obvious to the migration using data annotations.

```
[Table(“MonthlyPrice”)]
public partial class MonthlyPrice
{
    [Key]
    public int MpId { get; set; }        

    [ForeignKey("Markets")]
    public int MktId { get; set; }
    public Markets Mkt { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Commodities")]
    public int CmId { get; set; }
    public Commodities Cm { get; set; }

    public decimal MpPrice { get; set; }
    public Currencies Cur { get; set; }
    public PriceTypes Pt { get; set; }
    public UnitOfMeasure Um { get; set; }
}
[Table(“Commodities”)]
public partial class Commodities
{
    public Commodities()
    {
        MonthlyPriceItem = new HashSet<MonthlyPriceItem>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int CmId { get; set; }
    public string CmName { get; set; }
    public int CmCatId { get; set; }

    public ICollection<MonthlyPrice> MonthlyPriceItem { get; set; }
}

[Table(“Markets”)]
public partial class Markets
{
    [Key]
    public int MktId { get; set; }
    public string MktName { get; set; }
}
```

If recreating database:

```
Add-Migration awesome

Update-Database awesome
```

Else, if just adding a migration:

```
Add-Migration awesome –IgnoreChanges
```

I guess the great thing is, you have a golden opportunity to make it better than the last guy. Starting out with Same-Same on everything (table names, column names, keys, would be nice). Clean up all the differences.

There are clearly differences in both your table name and primary key names currently.

Comment: this is not a db-first approach

Comment: Evil spaces ruin everything. Database migrations included.